# Getting started with R and CFA

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I'm looking to run a CFA in R however I'm very new to the language in general. I've tried using the lavaan package but haven't been able to execute the code. I will keep studying R but thought I might get some help here.

Comment: It would be better if you post a question like: "How to run a CFA in R" after trying a little and, if you remain with doubts, post specifically the doubts you have, showing some examples of code you already tried.

Comment: Welcome Your (question in the form of a statement) is too broad so SO.  Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
After doing more [research(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this then study it:

```
install.packages("lavaan")
```

Within the package there contains a dataframe that you can learn from, most guides cover it, but I'll quickly go over what the code is doing since I just recently figured this one out.

```
x_vars <- HolzingerSwineford1939[,paste("x", 1:9, sep="")]
```

Assigns a part of the Holzinger data to X so you aren't working with the entire dataset. Look into functions more closely.

```
uniPlot(x_vars, type = "histogram")
```

Use this to plot your variables to make sure they are all normally distributed, as CFA can be thrown off by non-normal data.

```
#specify the model
HS.model <- ' visual =~ x1+ x2 +x3
              textual =~ x4+x5+x6
              speed =~ x7+x8+x9'
```

Now the specification model, read this as "Visual is MEASURED BY x1 and x2 and x3". The =~ indicates "measured by". So visual is measured by x1+ x2 + x3. Once you're done specifying, you can now fit the model:

```
#fit the model
fit <- cfa(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939,
           std.lv=T,
           missing= "fiml")
```

This will give you your fit statistics and tell you whether the items loaded correctly or not. Pretty simple package and I hope you get it!

Comment: This definitely helped me understand it more. Thanks!